# How do I solve this for $v_B$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cant figure out how to how to solve this for $v_B$. I tried dividing by $v_B$ on both sides of the equation, but that doesn't let me separate it on one side, and I am not able to get any further on it.

$$v_B=v_{CA}+v_{CB}-\frac{v_{CA}\cdot v_{CB}}{v_B}$$

Comment: Why don't you type the formula instead of having it as an image ?

Comment: Please confirm that projectilemotion's typed equation is correct. Are those $v$s with two subscripts real numbers or vectors? Stated differently, is that regular multiplication or the dot product?

Comment: Yes, projectilemotions equation is correct. That is regular multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using algebra you can get your equation to read

$$
v_B^2-(v_{CA}+v_{CB}) \cdot v_B + v_{CA} \cdot v_{CB}=0
$$

This is a quadratic equation in $v_B$ that is solved by

$$
v_B = \frac{(v_{CA}+v_{CB}) \pm \sqrt{{(v_{CA}+v_{CB})}^2 - 4 \cdot v_{CA} \cdot  v_{CB}}}{2} = \frac{(v_{CA}+v_{CB}) \pm |v_{CA}-v_{CB}|}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to visualize, I will let $v_B=x$, $v_{CA}=a$ and $v_{CB}=b$. Thus, you have:
$$x=a+b-\frac{a\cdot b}{x}$$
One may write:
$$x=\frac{x(a+b)}{x}-\frac{a\cdot b}{x}\implies x=\frac{x(a+b)-a\cdot b}{x}$$
This can be written as:
$$x^2=x(a+b)-ab$$
$$x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$$
Notice that this is now a quadratic equation. Can you apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) and solve for $x$?